# Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195' from server side

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I'm working on an MAC app that use iOS Push Notifications. I want to send the notification from a php script on my server. The code in my app works really good for registering for remote notification and receive them. I use this php script to send notification and it works well too:

```
 <?php

// My device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// My private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'myPrivateKeyPassword';

// My alert message here:
$message = 'New Push Notification!';

//badge
$badge = 1;

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
  exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

 echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

 // Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'badge' => $badge,
    'sound' => 'newMessage.wav'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload))  . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Error, notification not sent' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'notification sent!' . PHP_EOL;

 // Close the connection to the server
 fclose($fp);
?>
```

My problem is that if i run this script by terminal on my iMac as well as from other mac system, all works good and notifications are sent, but if I upload it on my server it doesn't work. My certificate is valid and it's in the same folder of the script. When i try to run the script on the server. Then it gives the following error:

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home/iphmuvxr/public_html/Schedueling/push_notification.php on line 25

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't open the port on your server.
Please open the port and try it again.

You can verify by following command:

```
$telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
```